# Creating a tree-view with buttons? in QT

Tags: c++, qt, dialog, tabs, treeview

I am trying to make a dialog box like below in QT, the only problem is I have no idea what the widget is called. The bar on the left is like a tree-view widget, but when you click on it, it updates the text on the right. Does anybody happen to know what the widget is called or what widget(s) are required to perform this? I am using QT C++ on Windows.

[image]

Comment: It's most likely a ListView, rather than a TreeView. Not sure exactly how Qt warps the native controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example with Qt showing you how to do this.

https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/4.8/dialogs-configdialog.html

If you're using Qt Creator as IDE, you can find it under the "Demos and Examples" tab in the Welcome Screen too.

It uses a QListWidget for the selector, and QStackedWidget to control the different pages. Connect the *currentItemChanged* signal of the list widget to change what page should be shown. Everything you'll need is in configdialog.cpp.

Answer (score 2):

If you realy need to add QPushButton into QListWidget, use setItemWidget, or into ListView use QAbstractItemView::setIndexWidget

Comment: Adding a button to a listview is not really necessary, just use currentItemChanged